# Audio controls don't show in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, html5-audio

The HTML5 audio controls in the audio elements on this page show and play just fine in every browser but IE. Can anyone enlighten me as to why they don't show in IE?
http://spartantheatre.org/radio.html

Comment: @Brad - Specifically IE9 but it doesn't show in any IE. I just noticed that, if I right click on the area where the controls should be and select play, the controls pop up and you can play the audio. However, I want them to show at all times, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, IE apparently requires preload to be set to 'auto'. It's been a while since I've worked on this page and had forgotten that. Modern browsers do not need that and setting it to auto causes each file to download parts of the audio file. Something I do not want to happen till I can rewrite the page.

IE is the worst browser on the planet.